# Trying to get property 'image_url' of non-object (View: /app/resources/views/library.blade.php)

Tags: laravel

My code keeps returning an error when I deploy to google cloud, but this works locally

> Trying to get property 'image_url' of non-object (View: /app/resources/views/library.blade.php)

In my view, I have

```
              @forelse($favorites as $fav)
                    <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                      <a href="{{ route('book', $fav->id) }}">
                      <img src="{{ $fav->book->image_url }}" alt="trending image" />
                      </a>
                      <p class="authorone">{{ $fav->book->author->name }}</p>
                      <h1 class="book-title">{{ $fav->book->name }}</h1>
                      @empty
                      <h2>You have no favourites</h2>
                      <br/><br/>
                      <a href="{{ route('discover') }}" class="return-button">Return To Discover</a>
                  </div>
               @endforelse
```

Here is my controller

```
public function mylibrary(){
   // $mybooks = MyBook::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
    $favorites = Favorite::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
    return view('library')->with('favorites', $favorites);

 }
```

In my `Favorite Model`, I have this

```
public function book ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Book::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

In my `Book Model`, I have this

```
public function favorites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
}
```

In my `User Model`, I have this

```
public function favorites(){
    return $this->hasMany(Favorite::class);
}
```

My favorites table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('favorites', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('book_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I don't know it's not working when I deploy to google cloud, but it works locally. I can't seems to figure out what I am doing wrong.

I also tried this

```
public function mylibrary(Book $book){
   // $mybooks = MyBook::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
    $favorites = Favorite::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
    return view('library')->with('favorites', $favorites)->with('book', $book);

 }
```

My Books schema

```
Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->text('about');
    $table->string('image');  
    $table->string('image_url');
    $table->string('epub_url');
    $table->integer('author_id'); 
    $table->string('publisher');  
    $table->year('year');
    $table->boolean('recommended')->default(0);
    $table->timestamps();    
});
```

Comment: `$fav->book` is `null`, so `$fav->book->image_url` won't work. Do a `dd($favourites)` and confirm that each `Favorite` has an associated `book`

Comment: It returns values.

Comment: It returns values... That's... Incredibly not useful lol. Your error is occurring while you're looping `$favourites`, so one of those iterations (`$fav`) does not have a `book` associated. It's up to you to debug which one and add some code to check for `book` before trying to access `book->whatever`.

Comment: Oh yes, I found out some doesn't have value. While some has value.

Comment: ^ There you go; so, while looping, check if `$fav->book` is a `book` or `null` and output accordingly.

Comment: Like this yeah $fav->book->image_url ?? ''

Comment: Or `$fav->book ? $fav->book->image_url : 'http://placehold.it/200/200'`; depends on your PHP version. (replace with a valid placeholder image URL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When querying, you may specify which relationships should be [eager
>   loaded](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) using the with method:
>   Blockquote

```
public function mylibrary() {
    $data = User::with('favorites', 'favorites.book')->find(Auth::id());
    return view('library')->with('userFavorites', $data);
}
```

You may check for null in chained statements using the [Null Coalescing Operator ??](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_coalescing_operator.htm) ( introduced in PHP 7) :

```
//...
<img src="{{ $fav->book->image_url ?? '' }}" alt="trending image" />
//...
```

**Edit**

```
@forelse($userFavorites->favorites as $fav)
     <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
         <a href="{{ route('book', $fav->id) }}">
            <img src="{{ $fav->book->image_url ?? '' }}" alt="trending image"/> 
         </a>
         <p class="authorone">{{ $fav->book->author->name ?? '' }}</p>
         <h1 class="book-title">{{ $fav->book->name ?? '' }}</h1>
@empty
         <h2>You have no favourites</h2>
         <br/><br/>
         <a href="{{ route('discover') }}" class="return-button">Return To Discover</a>
     </div>
@endforelse
```

Comment: Thanks it work, but it returned an empty box, because of the one that is null. How can I prevent this?